# Why my JTextField has changed after set new Border

Tags: java, swing, border, jtextfield

I would like to know why my element JTextField has change height after setting a new Border:

```
  packagesAddField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
```

after this code my JTextField changing a height (about 1px from upper and 1px from footer). It is possible, when i set some border he can change appearance of component?

Comment: yes border takes at least 1px to draw. where is the issue? are you using `null` layout?

Comment: im using javax.swing.GroupLayout. JTextField is in JPanel

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a word, don't. The [`setBorder()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setBorder-javax.swing.border.Border-) API recommends that you add the border to the enclosing container:

> Although technically you can set the border on any object that inherits from `JComponent`, the look and feel implementation of many standard Swing components doesn't work well with user-set borders. In general, when you want to set a border on a standard Swing component other than `JPanel` or `JLabel`, we recommend that you put the component in a `JPanel` and set the border on the `JPanel`.

Alternatively, consider an [`InputVerifier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification).