# How can I add an elliptical border to a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, border

I have an undecorated JFrame in the shape of an ellipse, that I would like to add a border.

I am hoping I don't have to implement the rootPane.paintComponent method, and that I can just do this by adding a border.

Is this possible in Java 7 or 8?

Comment: *"hoping I don't have to implement the paintComponent method"*  `JFrame` has no such method, so it would seem unlikely..

Answer (score 2):

In your implementation of `paintComponent()`, use `setClip()` with an `Ellipse2D` sized to match the image's `width` and `height`.

```
private Ellipse2D.Double border = new Ellipse2D.Double();
…
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent()
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    …
    int width = getWidth();
    int height = getHeight();
    g2d.setPaint(…);
    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    border.setFrame(0, 0, width, height);
    g2d.setClip(border);
    g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height, this);
}
```

Also override `getPreferredSize()`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5129757/230513).

Comment: So there's no way to do it using borders? I was hoping to use the stock selection of bevel and etched, etc

Comment: You can try implementing `Border`, but I see no advantage; see also this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24850292/230513).